# Multipeer connectivity custom invitation

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

For multipeer connectivity is there any way to customize the advertiser invitation? The UIalert that says "iPhone user would like to connect" I want to change it to say something else? I've tried it but I keep getting errors.

My code is below I separated the custom invitation at the bottom.

MPC HANDLER:

```
class MPCHANDLER: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate {

    var peerID:MCPeerID!
    var session:MCSession!
    var browser:MCBrowserViewController!
    var advertiser:MCAdvertiserAssistant? = nil
    var invitationHandler: ((Bool, MCSession?)->Void)!

    func setupPeerWithDisplayName (_ displayName:String){
        peerID = MCPeerID(displayName: displayName)
    }

    func setupSession(){
        session = MCSession(peer: peerID)
        session.delegate = self
    }

    func setupBrowser(){
        browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "game", session: session)

    }

    func advertiseSelf(_ advertise:Bool){
        if advertise{
            advertiser = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType: "game", discoveryInfo: nil, session: session)
            advertiser!.start()
        }else{
            advertiser!.stop()
            advertiser = nil
        }
    }


    func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
        let userInfo = ["peerID":peerID,"state":state.rawValue] as [String : Any]
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        })

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
        let userInfo = ["data":data, "peerID":peerID] as [String : Any]
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        })

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?) {

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {

    }

    func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }


}
```

VIEW CONTROLLER:

```
var currentPlayer:String!

var appDelegate:AppDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupPeerWithDisplayName(UIDevice.current.name)
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupSession()
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.advertiseSelf(true)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.peerChangedStateWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidChangeStateNotification"), object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MPC_DidReceiveDataNotification"), object: nil)

  }

@IBAction func LINK(_ sender: Any) {
    if appDelegate.MPCHandler.session != nil{
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.setupBrowser()
        appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.delegate = self

        self.present(appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
   }

           func peerChangedStateWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) 
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let state = userInfo["state"] as! Int

    if state != MCSessionState.connecting.rawValue{
        self.navigationItem.title = "Connected"
    }
}
        func handleReceivedDataWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    print(userInfo)
}

     func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

         func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    appDelegate.MPCHandler.browser.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

CUSTOM INVITATION:

```
func invitationWasReceived(_ fromPeer: String) {
self.createAlert(title: "HI", message: "TAP TO CONNECT TO USER")
}
 func createAlert (title: String, message:String)
 {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: output.text, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
  }
  }
```

Comment: @Eric Aya..thanks for the edit! :)

Answer (score 0):

`MCAdvertiserAssistant` is an high-level class. It implements most of the low-level operations itself, including the invitation alert. In order to create a custom invitation alert, you must use `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` instead as advertiser.

Define advertiser:

```
var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
```

Initialize:

```
advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peerID, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "hello-world")
advertiser.delegate = self
advertiser.startAdvertisingPeer()
```

And present your alert in delegate function:

```
func advertiser(_ advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: Data?, invitationHandler: @escaping (Bool, MCSession?) -> Void) {
    // Show custom alert here
}
```